# How to only allow same-origin in a flask request?

Tags: python, flask

##### My code

```py
@app.route('/create-api')  
def create_api():  
  if "example.org" in str(request.environ['werkzeug.request']): 
    # code
  else:
    return 401
```

##### The error

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, list, tuple with headers or status, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a int.
```

##### What I want

What I want to do is make it so that only my website can make requests.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a proper response from the Flask server.

```
@app.route('/create-api')  
def create_api():  
  if "example.org" in str(request.environ['werkzeug.request']): 
      # code
  else:
      return "Error message", 401
```